# How to locate the table id in Google Analytics?

Tags: java, google-analytics

I am doing the example (Java) at this link

> https://developers.google.com/analytics/resources/articles/gdataAnalyticsCsv

Please tell me how I can get the TABLE_ID in Google Analytics. The code in the link below uses the table id (line 37):

> https://code.google.com/p/ga-api-java-samples/source/browse/trunk/src/v2/csvprinter/AnalyticsCsvDemo.java

The table id needs to be used for other code. So, that "other code" is not going to work unless I can get the table id. Apparently, table id is of the form

> ga:[your_profile_id]

But this always results in the application getting terminated with the error:

> Invalid value for ids parameter: [my profile id here]

Please help me to solve this problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

In your analytics dashboard at the top left click on `ADMIN`, then go to `View Settings`, and you can find there the `View ID`. At the end just prepend `ga:` to that number.

So, at the end, your table id would be

```
ga:<view-id>
```

Answer (score 5):

In Google Analytics go to Admin -> Profiles -> Profile Settings.

The table id is the profile id. It is used by the GA api in the form of `ga:1234455`

So, if you have the right profile id in the table id, then something else is wrong.

**UPDATED**

In Google Analytics go to Admin -> View -> View Settings.

The view id is the profile id the profile id is the table id. Thank Google for being clear on this.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

In the `View` panel, select `View Settings`, then under `Basic Settings` there is the `View ID` just append `ga:` before that id.

Correct place below: [image]

Comment: Just to be sure, it is not `PROPERTY ID`? I can't find it!

Comment: I also don't see a "View Settings"